# Proton VPN ate my routing table/internet connection

Tags: networking, routing, vpn, manjaro

After installing Proton VPN on a Manjaro system I lost the ability to connect to the internet even though my wireless router shows that the IP address (192.168.1.36) for the system is connected.  Based on some research I found that the routing table had been modified as follows:

192.168.1.36 Proton VPN impacted routing table:

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
```

Another Manjaro system on the same network with a working internet connection and without Proton VPN installed has the following routing table which matches the IP address listed in the wireless router settings:

192.168.1.23 internet connected system routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.23 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.23 metric 600
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.23 metric 600
```

After removing the 10.0.2.2 table with `ip route flush metric 100` and then attempting to create a default gateway with a `ip route add default via 192.168.1.36 dev enp0s3` command I receive the following error:

```
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

and have not found the correct options to the `ip route` command to create what I believe should work given the 192.168.1.23 routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.36 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.36 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.36 metric 100
```

I have also created a file at `/etc/systemd/network/enp0s3.network` and run `systemctl stop NetworkManager.service` as described in https://www.howtogeek.com/799588/how-to-set-the-default-gateway-in-linux/.

Any help in creating the desired table is appreciated and if additional information would be helpful I can include it as needed.